# Integrating an Action Bar with Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm trying to set up an application that allows users to find local businesses and events.  I had a working map, but I'm having trouble getting it to integrate into a tabbed action bar. Unfortunately it says "Unfortunately, [app] has stopped."
any help would be greatly appreciated.

ActionBarMain.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ActionBarMain extends Activity implements TabListener {
    RelativeLayout rl;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_main);
        try {
            rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Map").setTabListener(this));
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Businesses").setTabListener(this));
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Events").setTabListener(this));
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Facebook").setTabListener(this));

            bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            bar.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        /**
         * Hiding Action Bar
         */
    }

    Fragment fram1;
    FragmentTransaction fragMentTra = null;
    FragMent2 fram2;
    FragMent3 fram3;
    FragMent4 fram4;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_action_bar_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (tab.getText().equals("Map")) {
            try {
                rl.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            fram1 = new Fragment();
            fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram1);
            fragMentTra.commit();
        } else if (tab.getText().equals("Businesses")) {
            try {
                rl.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            fram2 = new FragMent2();
            fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram2);
            fragMentTra.commit();
        } else if (tab.getText().equals("Events")) {
            try {
                rl.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            fram3 = new FragMent3();
            fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram3);
            fragMentTra.commit();
        } else if (tab.getText().equals("Facebook")) {
            try {
                rl.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            fram2 = new FragMent2();
            fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
            fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram2);
            fragMentTra.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

}
```

FragMent1.java:

```
public class FragMent1 extends FragmentActivity{

SupportMapFragment mMap;
GoogleMap googleMap;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_main);

       mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.mainGrid);

        googleMap = mMap.getMap();
 }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ahmad.actionBar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.ahmad.actionbar.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ahmad.actionbar.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:allowBackup="True">
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="super_secret_key"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ahmad.actionbar.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActionBarMain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar_main"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:

fixed a few errors of trying to integrate two apps together and added new logcat.

logcat:

```
04-24 21:34:33.242: D/AndroidRuntime(11335): Shutting down VM
04-24 21:34:33.242: W/dalvikvm(11335): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e26930)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ahmad.actionBar/com.ahmad.actionbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ahmad.actionbar.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.ahmad.actionBar-2.apk
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ahmad.actionbar.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.ahmad.actionBar-2.apk
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
04-24 21:34:33.252: E/AndroidRuntime(11335):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says "class MainActivity not found".

The class you posted is named ActionBarMain while your Manifest file says MainActivity is your main class.

If you don't have any MainActivity in your project and you want ActionBarMain to be your first Activity. Then replace ActionBarMain with MainAcitivty in your manifest file.

Comment: thanks. I started with a working map and a working tabbed action bar. just mistakes of combining them together.

Comment: so did it fix the problem?

Comment: It wasn't the last problem in there, but I was able to work out the rest of it and have it up and running now. thanks again.